# How to properly build an angular 1.5 text box component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is pretty much self explanatory.
I have build a text box :

```
<qn-textbox placeholder="" 
            label="{{$ctrl.resources.lbl_PersonalId}}"></qn-textbox>
```

and the component looks like this :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var qnTextbox = {
        bindings: {
            placeholder: '@',
            label: '@'
        },
        template: `
            <div clas="row">
                <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <span data-ng-bind="$ctrl.label"></span>
                </div>
                <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
        controller: function () {
            var ctrl = this;
        }
    };

    angular
      .module('app.components.core.qnTextbox')
      .component('qnTextbox', qnTextbox);

})();
```

I'm looking for the correct way to bubble up / inform the parent when the text changes.
 - should i use some kind of text container and then make sure each text box      component has it as parent so i can use the require (then $onChange will update the container) ? 
- is it overhead ? (i think not ,but i might be wrong)
I'm looking for something generic and clean .

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-model` to store the data, and use `ng-change` to detect changes to the form data.

---

Template:

`<input ng-model="$ctrl.model" ng-change="$ctrl.onModelChange()"></input>`

---

Detect the change in your controller:

```
$ctrl.onModelChange = function() {
    console.log($ctrl.model);
}
```